# How to store Dataframe value as rowkey as well as column using Hortonworks-spark shc?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I am using shc-core to write spark Dataset to hbase, for more details see [here](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc).

This is my current shc catalog:

```
def catalog = s"""{
        |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table1"},
        |"rowkey":"key",
        |"columns":{
          |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
          |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"boolean"},
          |"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"col2", "type":"double"},
          |"col3":{"cf":"cf3", "col":"col3", "type":"float"},
          |"col4":{"cf":"cf4", "col":"col4", "type":"int"},
          |"col5":{"cf":"cf5", "col":"col5", "type":"bigint"},
          |"col6":{"cf":"cf6", "col":"col6", "type":"smallint"},
          |"col7":{"cf":"cf7", "col":"col7", "type":"string"},
          |"col8":{"cf":"cf8", "col":"col8", "type":"tinyint"}
        |}
      |}""".stripMargin
```

Because the sof rule code cannot be too long,I can only give you part of it:

This is my HBase catalog :

```
{
    "columns": {
        "RXSJ": {
            "col": "RXSJ",
            "cf": "info",
            "type": "bigint"
        },
        "LATITUDE": {
            "col": "LATITUDE",
            "cf": "info",
            "type": "float"
        },
        "ZJHM": {
            "col": "ZJHM",
            "cf": "rowkey",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AGE": {
            "col": "AGE",
            "cf": "info",
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "rowkey": "ZJHM",
    "table": {
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "mongo_hbase_spark_out"
    }
}
```

The other fields output normally, but the rowkey column is not output.

[image]

How can I output the rowkey additionaly as a column?

Comment: What is your question? Post reproducible code! The one you posted doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: The hbase catalog is my code generated results,

Comment: Thanks,my  problem is How to output rowkey column?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get the `rowkey` visible in the same way as the other columns. In the [description of the HBase Catalog](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc#defined-the-hbase-catalog) it is mentioned:

> Note that the rowkey also has to be defined in details as a column (col0), which has a specific cf (rowkey).

Therefore, it will not show up although you have specified it in the `columns` section of your catalog.

The `rowkey` is only visible as actual rowkey as your screenshot also shows.

Comment: Thank you help me, I know rowkey is column,It does output to the first column. But i want output to  COLUMN+CELL.That's the second column

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Indeed, I found col0 before, but it didn't output after modification

Answer (score 0):

After testing, I solved the problem.
The whole idea is to output the same column twice

This is my new generated SHC catalog:

```
{
    "columns": {
        "rowkey_ZJHM": {
            "col": "ZJHM",
            "cf": "rowkey",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ZJHM": {
            "col": "ZJHM",
            "cf": "info",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "AGE": {
            "col": "AGE",
            "cf": "info",
            "type": "int"
        }
    },
    "rowkey": "ZJHM",
    "table": {
        "namespace": "default",
        "name": "mongo_hbase_spark_out"
    }
}
```

[image: hbase scan result]

I think rowkey column is Hortonworks-spark shc special column,it always output first column. Only think other ways to output to other cf.

Let me know if you have any better Suggestions

Thanks!